# How do I make an image I use be both a background image and stretch to fit the window that I make

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code that i'm currently using for the background

```
def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image = photo)
    label.image = photo #avoid garbage collection

image = Image.open('tlr.png')
copy_of_image = image.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = ttk.Label(root, image = photo)
label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = YES)
```

I am trying to do something like this

```
background_image=tk.PhotoImage(...)
background_label = tk.Label(parent, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

But I don't understand the syantax and I don't know a place where I can look it up AND have it to be newbie to coding

thank you for reading and thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Pick one from [`[python][tkinter] background image`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+background+image)

Comment: For image processing, see [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).  For `tkinter`, see [`An Introduction to Tkinter`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm).